# what are the best practices for localization in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

What are the best practices for language(localization) in Umbraco? We have  tried to add dropdown option with language code on it and added a page with postfix on their name example (Default-NL, Default-US).

Can you give me some pointers to be read of any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently developed a multi-territory, multi-language site and I handled the content tree much as Marapet has described. Each language defined as a separate branch under the root node.

You can define a "umbracoUrlName" property of the DocumentType for a language homepage which will allow you to specify a 2-character code for the URL path whilst retaining a more descriptive title for the page.

With regards to the localization, I personally use Umbraco's dictionary feature for setting internal translations, e.g. DocumentType names, Property names and Descriptions. This is so that CMS user's can use Umbraco in different languages.

The limitation of the Dictionary is that all values are held in a database so it does not function like .Net resource files. For example, if no translation exists for a specific language for a key in the dictionary, an empty string will be served. Ideally, you would want the kind of fallback value that .Net resource files offer. For this reason, I implement a custom section for maintaining resource files and values for use in the published sites.

I can define a Invariant resource with default values which each language site can fall back to if no overriding language has been defined.

The other advantage of this is that I can ensure that CMS authors do not need access to the Settings section of the CMS.

Comment: cool. thanks for your answer. i'm in the process of building the structure of my umbraco project and still figuring out what would be the best way to do it.

Comment: I would very much advise checking out [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org) for help on these sorts of things if you haven't already.

Comment: With regards to having a fallback value in Razor at least I am using the following @Library.Coalesce(Dictionary.Search, "Search") to overcome this shortfall.

Comment: note: you can move the dictionary out of the settings section.

Comment: @Myster Can you expand on this, and put it in an answer? It doesn't make any sense without saying how.

Comment: @Digbyswift it's not an answer on it's own, I just mention it becuase you say the dictionary is in the settings section, which is true, however it can be moved to another section which the user does have access to. Change the "application" attribute (eg to 'translation') in the trees.config file (In earlier versions it's done by editing the 'appAlias' column in the 'umbracoAppTree' table in the database.)

Answer (score 5):

- Use the **[dictionary](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/umbraco-help/settings/editdictionaryitem)** : Add languages to the Umbraco settings, and translate text to be localized in the dictionary.
- **[Manage hostnames](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-client/context-menus)** : By assigning the appropriate language to the rootnode(s), the culture will be set to this language by Umbraco, and the corresponding date settings, dictionary items, etc. will be used.
- For [multi-language sites](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multi-lingual-sites-under-a-single-domain), you'll probably want to have a document tree for each language and set the hostname/language settings appropriately. Of course you should be able to use the same templates for every language (use the dictionary, no static text in the templates). A common workflow is to set up the web site in you main language, then copy the entire document tree and translate it.

Comment: thanks marapet. these are nice articles.